# Replace specific characters (CR and LF) in a file

Tags: assembly, x86

## Context

This program has been created to "fix" files originating from Cobol databases. In Cobol, files extracted via something called a "copy" have the same number of characters per line. However, user inputs might include new line characters which can cause problems when interpreted by other systems.

This program aims to solve this by replacing CR/LF characters in the file, except the END OF LINE sequence (LF).

## Code

```
; This programs reads from STDIN
; It sends this content back to STDOUT
; It replaces CR (0xd) and LF (0xa) by space (0x20)
; It reads a number from invocation parameters (1 to 255 --> 1 byte number only)
; This number represents the number of character per ligne and must not
;   take into account the EOL LF.
; The EOL LF will not be replaced
; If the parameter number is incorrect, output will not be correctly formatted
; (you will lose EOL LF)

; Compile and link with:
; ld -o main.exe main.o -m elf_i386 && 
; nasm -f elf -ggdb -F stabs main.asm

; Run with:
;  ./main.exe 8 <toto.txt
; Where toto contains:
; 1234|678
; 1234|<cr>
; 7
; 1234|678
; 1234|
; 78
; Output:
;/app/asm # ./main.exe 8 <toto.txt
; 1234|678
; 1234|  7
; 1234|678
; 1234| 78

section .data

section .bss
    line_length: resb 1
    count_buffer: resb 1
    input_buffer: resb 1

section .text
    global _start
    _start:

        mov byte [count_buffer], 0

        ; using ATOI, gets the first command line argument, transform it into
        ; a number.
        _get_line_length:
            mov eax, 0
            mov ecx, [esp+8] ; ecx pointe sur la stack à l'emplacement du premier parametre

            _atoi:
                movzx esi, byte [ecx] ; store into esi a the byte at adress where ecx points to

                cmp esi, 0              ; compare esi with 0 (NULL char)
                jz _check_line_length   ; if esi = 0, jump to _check_line_length

                cmp esi, 48             ; compare esi with 48 ("0" char)
                jl _exit_1              ; if esi is lower than 0, exit in error

                cmp esi, 57             ; compare esi with 57 ("9" char)
                jg _exit_1              ; if esi is greater, exit in error

                sub esi, 48             ; substract 48 to esi (transforms the char into its decimal equivalent)
                imul eax, 10            ; multiply eax by 10
                add eax, esi            ; add esi to eax
                inc ecx                 ; make ecx point to the next byte
                jmp _atoi               ; jump to _atoi (loop)

        _check_line_length:
            cmp eax, 0
            jz _exit_1  ; TODO message erreur
            jl _exit_1  ; TODO message erreur
            add al, 1   ; Take expected linefeed into account (the mandatory LF)
            push ax     ; push al (ax because can't push less that 16 bits) to the stack. Acces later via [esp]

        _read_stdin:

            add byte [count_buffer], 1  ; increase loop counter

            mov eax, 3
            mov ebx, 0
            mov ecx, input_buffer
            mov edx, 1
            int 80H

            cmp eax, -1 ; if error, exit input
            jz _exit_1
            cmp eax, 0 ; if 0, then no more content to read
            jz _exit_0

            xor eax, eax
            mov ax, [esp]  ; get the line length. We get two bytes, the lower end is in al, the higher one is in ah
            mov ah, [count_buffer] ; get the current loop counter

            cmp al, ah  ; compare nbr char read and line length

            jz _finish_process_line

            jmp _process_char

        _finish_process_line:
            mov byte [count_buffer], 0
            jmp _stdout

        _process_char:
            mov ecx, [ecx]  ; store the value of the memory ecx points at to the ecx reg
            cmp cl, 0xa ; compare the lower byte of ecx 32 bits to LF
            jz .replace_char
            cmp cl, 0xd
            jz .replace_char ; compare the lower byte of ecx 32 bits to CR
            jmp _stdout

            .replace_char:
                xor ecx, ecx    ; clean the ecx reg
                mov cl, 20h    ; set cl reg to space
                mov [input_buffer], cl ; move value to input_buffer memory
                jmp _stdout

        _stdout:
            mov eax, 4
            mov ebx, 1
            mov edx, 1
            mov ecx, input_buffer
            int 80H
            jmp _read_stdin

        _exit_0:
            mov eax, 1
            mov ebx, 0
            int 80H

        _exit_1:
            mov eax, 1
            mov ebx, 1
            int 80H
```

## Questions

This program is "slow". With an input file of 43 858 bytes, it takes 0.087 seconds to execute.  So arround 504 115 bytes per second.

I have a python program that does the equivalent, which is capable of processing 12 Gb in 24 minutes, so arround 8 333 333 bytes per second.

**Is it possible to increase performances ?**

Comment: Use the python program. It makes no sense to write assembler for today modern high speed CPUs, as those CPUs have highly complex auto mechanism which are not even fully understood by their developers. But if you really want to improve your assembler program, think about a better input/output system with streams/pipelines, that's mostly the bottle neck. If you ask me, just use C and a modern C compiler, it's way easier and more performant than writing a not optimized assembler program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A major improvement would be to read/write more than one character at a time. System calls of any kind and especially I/O like it is the case here, always introduce a lot of overhead.

And since your, from Cobol databases originating, files have the same number of characters per line, that's the amount to read/write in one go.

Below is my implementation for this. I have also improved other aspects of the code:

- simplified the *atoi* character validation and conversion
- removed checking for negative numerical input which is not possible in this code
- added checking for an input exceeding 255
- the code that processes a complete line got much simpler than what you had written for dealing with just a single character...

```
section .data

section .bss
    line_length:  resd 1
    input_buffer: resb 256

section .text
    global _start
    _start:

_get_line_length:
    xor   eax, eax
    mov   ecx, [esp + 8]       ; pointe à l'emplacement du premier paramètre
_atoi:
    movzx esi, byte [ecx]
    test  esi, esi
    jz    _check_line_length
    sub   esi, "0"
    cmp   esi, 9
    ja    _exit_1
    imul  eax, 10
    add   eax, esi
    inc   ecx
    jmp   _atoi

_check_line_length:            ; Expected input [1,255]
    test  eax, eax
    jz    _exit_1              ; TODO message erreur
    cmp   eax, 255
    ja    _exit_1              ; TODO message erreur
    inc   eax                  ; Take mandatory linefeed into account
    mov   [line_length], eax   ; Valid [2,256]

_read_stdin:
    mov   eax, 3
    mov   ebx, 0
    mov   ecx, input_buffer
    mov   edx, [line_length]
    int   80h                  ; -> EAX
    cmp   eax, -1              ; if error, exit input
    je    _exit_1
    cmp   eax, [line_length]
    jne   _exit_0

_process_line:
    lea   esi, [eax - 2]       ; EAX=[2,256] -> ESI=[0,254]
.next_char:
    cmp   byte [input_buffer + esi], 13
    je    .replace_char
    cmp   byte [input_buffer + esi], 10
    jne   .keep_char
.replace_char:
    mov   byte [input_buffer + esi], 32
.keep_char:
    dec   esi
    jns   .next_char           ; Stops looping at ESI=-1

_stdout:
    mov   eax, 4
    mov   ebx, 1
    mov   ecx, input_buffer
    mov   edx, [line_length]
    int   80h
    jmp   _read_stdin
```

### Going for something better

The above proposed solution is not perfect! If it so happens that the (user-inputted) linelength is very small, then the revised program would still be doing a lot of I/O operations.
Although it is true that loading the file whole would reduce the number of necessary I/O operations to just one read and one write, in practice we would use a big buffer capable of holding large chunks of the file. In the below code I apply this technique.
A *bytes_per_io_request* is calculated such that every chunk of the file can provide the program with a whole number of lines.

```
section .data

section .bss
    BUFFERSIZE equ 1048576      ; Arbitrarily chosen size of 1MB

    line_length:          resd 1
    bytes_per_io_request: resd 1
    input_buffer:         resb BUFFERSIZE

section .text
    global _start
    _start:

_get_line_length:
    xor   eax, eax
    mov   ecx, [esp + 8]       ; pointe à l'emplacement du premier paramètre
_atoi:
    movzx esi, byte [ecx]
    test  esi, esi
    jz    _check_line_length
    sub   esi, "0"
    cmp   esi, 9
    ja    _exit_1
    imul  eax, 10
    add   eax, esi
    inc   ecx
    jmp   _atoi

_check_line_length:            ; Expected input [1,255]
    test  eax, eax
    jz    _exit_1              ; TODO message erreur
    cmp   eax, 255
    ja    _exit_1              ; TODO message erreur
    inc   eax                  ; Take mandatory linefeed into account
    mov   [line_length], eax   ; Valid [2,256]

    mov   eax, BUFFERSIZE
    xor   edx, edx
    div   dword [line_length]
    imul  eax, [line_length]
    mov   [bytes_per_io_request], eax

_read_stdin:
    mov   edx, [bytes_per_io_request]
    mov   ecx, input_buffer
    mov   ebx, 0
    mov   eax, 3
    int   80h                  ; -> EAX
    cmp   eax, -1              ; if error, exit input
    je    _exit_1

_process_group_of_lines:
    mov   edi, [line_length]   ; CONST
    xor   edx, edx             ; EDX:EAX is NumberOfBytes that were actually read
    div   edi                  ; -> EAX is NumberOfLines (This should divide evenly)
    test  edx, edx
    jnz   _exit_0              ; Error out on partial line ? Or just ignore it.
    test  eax, eax
    jz    _done                ; No lines in curent I/O request, so at end-of-file

    mov   ebx, input_buffer
_process_line:
    lea   esi, [edi - 2]       ; EDI=[2,256] -> ESI=[0,254]
.next_char:
    cmp   byte [ebx + esi], 13
    je    .replace_char
    cmp   byte [ebx + esi], 10
    jne   .keep_char
.replace_char:
    mov   byte [ebx + esi], 32
.keep_char:
    dec   esi
    jns   .next_char           ; Stops looping at ESI=-1
    add   ebx, edi             ; Move to next line
    dec   eax
    jnz   _process_line

_stdout:
    lea   edx, [ebx - input_buffer]
    mov   ecx, input_buffer
    mov   ebx, 1
    mov   eax, 4
    int   80h
    jmp   _read_stdin

_done:
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

### First, a Frame Challenge

Assembler isn’t the best tool for this job.  It’s not likely that this kind of processing of text files is going to need every edge it can get with performance.  If it did, a good C, C++ or Rust compiler (among others) should be able to do a good job on it.

### How to Improve the Performance

First—unless you need to run this on something like a pipe—map the input file to memory instead of reading it with repeated system calls, and transform the data in place.

Second, vectorize your code.  On a modern `x86_64` architecture, that probably means making a bitmask of all the characters to be replaced, and replacing them with an instruction like `vpblendvb`.

### An Example

This is not extensively tested, but it’ll serve as a comparison.  Here’s a reasonably-similar program in C that takes two command-line arguments, the line length and the path of the input file, and writes the results to standard output.

The original program is not portable across operating systems, so I didn’t bother supporting anything but POSIX, but there’s a portable alternative to `open()/mmap()` in `glib`, if you need one.

```c
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE   700

#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>    // open
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h> // mmap
#include <sys/stat.h> // fstat


/* Abort with an error message that includes the line number, the system
 * error string, and what the program was doing.
 */
void fatal_system_error_helper( const char* const msg,
                                const char* const sourcefile,
                                const int line,
                                const int err )
{
    fflush(stdout);
    fprintf( stderr,
             "Error %s (%s:%d): %s\n",
             msg,
             sourcefile,
             line,
             strerror(err) );
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

#define fatal_system_error(msg) \
  fatal_system_error_helper( (msg), __FILE__, __LINE__, errno )


/* Returns the size of the open file with descroptor fd.
 * Returns successfully or crashes the program.
 */
size_t get_size_fd(const int fd)
{
    struct stat buf;
    errno = 0;
    const int error = fstat( fd, &buf );
    if (error != 0) {
        fatal_system_error("Getting stats on the input file.");
    }
    assert(buf.st_size >= 0);
    return (size_t)buf.st_size;
}


/* Replaces all instances of '\r' and `\n` within the input range with spaces.
 * a character at the end pointer is not replaced.
 */
static void replace_chars( char* const start, const char* const end )
{
    assert(start <= end);
    for ( char* p = start; p < end; ++p ) {
        const char c = *p;
        *p = (c == '\r' || c == '\n') ? ' '
                                      : c;
    }
}


int main( const int argc, const char * const argv[] )
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s <line length> <input_file>.\n", argv[0] );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    assert(argv[1]);
    const long int length_param = atol(argv[1]);
    assert(length_param > 0);
    const size_t line_len = (size_t)length_param;

    assert(argv[2]);
    errno = 0;
    const int fd_in = open( argv[2], O_RDONLY );
    if (fd_in < 0) {
        fatal_system_error("Opening input file");
    }

    const size_t input_len = get_size_fd(fd_in);

    errno = 0;
    char* const input_data = mmap( NULL,
                                   input_len,
                                   PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                                   MAP_PRIVATE,
                                   fd_in,
                                   0 );

    if (input_data == MAP_FAILED) {
        fatal_system_error("mapping file to memory");
    }

    char* current_line = input_data;

    while (current_line + line_len < input_data + input_len ) {
        char* const next_line = current_line + line_len;
        replace_chars( current_line, next_line - 1 );
        current_line = next_line;
    }

    /* Pick up any straggling input. */
    replace_chars( current_line, input_data + input_len );
    fwrite( input_data, 1, input_len, stdout );

    // All files closed on program termination.
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The inner loop here is `replace_chars`.

```c
    for ( char* p = start; p < end; ++p ) {
        const char c = *p;
        *p = (c == '\r' || c == '\n') ? ' '
                                      : c;
    }
```

It would be possible to get fancier here, for example using a second bitmask to mark all the end-of-line positions as not to be replaced, and rotating it on each iteration of the inner loop.

On ICX 2022, with the flags `-std=c17 -march=x86-64-v3 -O3` ([link to Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fWsPMozPq)), the compiler inlines this function into `main` and compiles the inner loop as:

```
.LBB2_23:                               #   Parent Loop BB2_10 Depth=1
        vmovdqu         xmm3, xmmword ptr [rbp + rdi]
        vpcmpeqb        xmm4, xmm3, xmm0
        vpcmpeqb        xmm5, xmm3, xmm1
        vpor            xmm4, xmm5, xmm4
        vpblendvb       xmm3, xmm3, xmm2, xmm4
        vmovdqu         xmmword ptr [rbp + rdi], xmm3
        add             rdi, 16
        cmp             rdi, rcx
        jbe     .LBB2_23
```

It’s finicky about just how you have to write the conditional expression, but modern compilers can do a very good job optimizing code like this, and code in a high-level language is much more portable and maintainable.